# React - Downloading a Zip File from API Response Body in Bytes String?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binary, zip, byte

I have a working API call that returns in the response body a string prepared in Bytes format on the Python side that is a zip file. The String looks something like this, but longer:
PK��Q��F���������������/export_file.csv��uX\M�

This is a zip file containing one csv file. In tools such as postman, hitting the same POST endpoint with the same parameters in the body, I can successfully download a valid zip file, unzip the contents, and view the .csv file. In the browser debugger tools, I can see the API endpoint returning a successful response, with the same string above in the body.

Where I have **failed at every attempt** is on the react side, doing the work necessary to take this string and download the same zip file. Every suggestion I've read on SO and everywhere else has failed me. Here is what some of my failed attempts look like:

(Also note that a successful API call returns a 26kb payload from this example)

```
export function downloadZipFile(responseBody){

  /* Blob Attempts */

  // These download a 46kb file. Attempting to open gives "The compressed zip folder is invalid"
  // var blob = new Blob([responseBody], {type: "content-type"}); 
  // var blob = new Blob([responseBody], {type: "application/zip"}); 
  // var blob = new Blob([responseBody], {type: "application/zip, application/octet-stream"}); 
  // var blob = new Blob([responseBody], {type: "application/octet-stream"}); 
  // var blob = new Blob([responseBody], {type: "octet/stream"}); 

  var fileName = "export.zip";
  saveAs(blob,fileName);


  /* Data String Attempts */

  // const dataStr = "data:application/zip;" + responseBody; // "Failed - Network Error"
  // const dataStr = "data:application/zip, application/octet-stream;" + responseBody; // Downloads 1kb File "The compressed zip folder is invalid"
  // const dataStr = "data:application/zip,application/octet-stream;" + responseBody; // Downloads 1kb File "The compressed zip folder is invalid"
  // const dataStr = "data:application/octet-stream;" + responseBody; // "Failed - Network Error"

  let downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
  downloadElement.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  downloadElement.setAttribute("download", "export.zip");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadElement); 
  downloadElement.click();
  downloadElement.remove();

}
```

Comment: How do you trigger the download and get `responseBody`? You should let the browser download the file by providing the API endpoint url directly and not use any kind of AJAX call.

Comment: Did you try this? https://digitaldrummerj.me/node-download-zip-and-extract/

Comment: downloadElement.setAttribute('href','data:application/zip;charset=utf8,'+ encodeURIComponent(responseBody));

Comment: @ChristosLytras There are solutions like creating a temporal link and triggering to download an api response as file.

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehrvarzi I don't understand why did you tag my name but that is exactly what I proposed to the OP. Also the question itself demonstrates what you are trying to tell to me. (Look at the bottom you'll see a `let downloadElement = document.createElement('a'); ... downloadElement.click(); ...` and that is a temporary link).

Answer (score 6):

I've arrived late, but hope to help someone.

It is really important to set responseType as 'arraybuffer' in the api call, like this:

```
...
export const getZip = async (id) => {
   const { data } = await axios.get(
      "/sypa-applications/export",
      {
        id
      },
      { responseType: "arraybuffer" } 
      );

   return data;
 }
 ...
```

Then you can download the ZIP from both ways:

1.- Using file-saver npm dependency:

```
   let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/zip" });
   saveAs(blob, "fileName.zip");
```

2.- Using DOM:

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: "application/zip" });
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute("download", "fileName.zip");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

I couldn't download the ZIP until I set the responseType param to "arraybuffer" in the GET request.

Best regard,
Alberto.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this tool? https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/
There is an example for unzipping a file using js in the browser. http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo2.html

It seems that this is what you want. First unzip the file and the use the .csv as wanted